# Failed MacOS file sharing using wrong user account - how to reset?

Tags: macos, smb, file-sharing

I have two Macbook Pros:

- Mac1 is 16' 2019 running Big Sur 11.2.3
- Mac2 is 13' 2017 running Catalina 10.15.7.

I am encountering this weird problem while trying to access file on Mac1 from Mac2 via MacOS's File Sharing. In Mac2's Finder, I use smb://Mac1 to open Mac1, but although occasionally it is successful, most of the time it just times out before popping up saying 'connection failed'. However, I can open Mac1 from my iPad very easily. So I guess something wrong on Mac2.

I checked sys logs in Console app and found something maybe relevant:

```
KernelEventAgent   tid 657c52ee type 'smbfs', mounted on '/Volumes/mac1', from '//ABCD@ufo20mbp._smb._tcp.local/mac1', not responding
KernelEventAgent   tid 657c52ee type 'smbfs', mounted on '/Volumes/mac1', from '//ABCD@ufo20mbp._smb._tcp.local/mac1', dead
```

in which ABCD IS NOT the correct account name to login on Mac1. I highly believe this could be the reason why the connection fails, but I cannot find any place to reset the account name. I am not sure if I am correct but I tried smb://XYZ@mac1 in Finder, but no luck, in which XYZ is the right login account name on Mac1.

Please advice what I should be to fix this issue.

Comment: Are the user ids of the XYZ user the same on both Macs `id -u` will give the userid

Comment: on Mac1 and Mac2, I am using same account name `XYZ` and they are of same user ids (same results of `id -u`).

Comment: On the other side, the two Macbooks are good to send files via AirDrop. This could help a little bit, but my goal is to mount Mac1's folder onto Mac2 so I can work with it like a local env.

Comment: I use the ip address instead of the name.

Answer (score 1):

Network share credentials are stored in `Keychain Access.app`. Take a look there. You may search for `ABCD` to quickly find any credentials containing this login. You can then just delete the wrong items.

Please note, when using <kbd>⌘ K</kbd> in Finder, your connection string needs to look like this:

`smb://<ip address>` e.g. `smb://192.168.0.123`

or

`smb://<local hostname>` e.g. `smb://targetMacName.local` ([how to find/change local hostname](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-computers-local-hostname-mac-mchlp2322/mac))